# Is it desirable to establish a CAD-like geometry medium for four dimensional space-time topologies and FEM?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, finite-element-method

Finite element and numerical methods over 4d space-time is a topic of interest for elastodynamics right now. Do you think it is desirable to establish a geometry/CAD system for space-time involving simulations?
[Here is a great paper on the numerical methods, integration, and FEM on the space-time](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/347397908_Foundations_of_space-time_finite_element_methods_polytopes_interpolation_and_integration)

Comment: do you have a mathematical question? (that is when you will most likely get a helpful response).

Comment: As stated, this looks like a yes/no question, as in a poll. As such, it doesn't seem like an ideal question for MathOverflow. Since it looks like a poll, I'll make it Community Wiki (but the community may decide it's not quite right for this site).

Comment: The most useless man in the world has just got roasted by an 83 h-index scholar... I can't even feel bad, I feel honored sir.